# Evaluation with map, apply of function, and vector of quoted expressions

Tags: clojure

What is the correct way to think about the following?

```
user=> (map #(apply println %) ['(+ 1 1)])
+ 1 1
;=> (nil)
```

I have in my head that this should possibly print `2` and not what it does print.  I have a notion that the quoted `'(+ 1 1)` should be evaluated once to be the data `(+ 1 1)` when it is inside of `[]`, and again `(+ 1 1)` should be evaluated to `2` when `apply` puts it in the argument position of `println`.

Here is how I am kind of picturing evaluation:

```
(map #(apply println %) ['(+ 1 1)])
; --> to reader
(<map-function-var> <anonymous-println-function-var> [(+ 1 1)])
; --> <map-function-var> applys the <anonymous-println-function-var> to the args:
[(#(apply println %) [(+ 1 1)])]
; --> apply the argument
[(println (+ 1 1)]
; --> eval it
[(println 2]
; --> print it
2
;=> nil
```

My mental model obviously has one too many evaluations in it, and I think the last one, where `2` is produced, is where it is wrong, but I am not sure.  Can someone explain how I should be thinking of this sequence of substitutions and evaluations?

Update: it may have something to do with this?

```
user=> (map #(apply println %) [(list "a" "b") (list "c" "d")])
a b
c d
(nil nil)
```

Once the contents of `[]` are evaluated, they are now data, and when they are passed to `#(apply println %)`, they are considered data, as the elements of `[]` have been evaluated, and will not be passed to the evaluator to try and find the function `"a"` or `"c"`... ?

Comment: One way to think about the quote in the first example of `'(+ 1 1)` is that the quote is in some sense _forever_ preventing the evaluation of that form. The _quote itself_ gets evaluated, and the value is simply a list with three elements, the symbol `+`, a `1`, and a `1`.  That you can print or do with what you like. A list is just a list, you can evaluate it if you want, but it's just a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) returns a lazy sequence and you shouldn't use it for side effects (like printing).

There are ways to force all side effects in the lazy sequence ([`dorun`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun), [`doall`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall)), but in this case, you can directly use [`run!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!) or [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq).

As for the main problem: `(+ 1 1)` is just the way how REPL prints the result of the expression `'(+ 1 1)` (a result of that expression is a list with one symbol and two numbers).
But if you just copy-paste that printed representation into REPL, you will get Clojure expression evaluating to `2`.

Following [Evaluation reference article](https://clojure.org/reference/evaluation), I will try to describe what is going on when you call `(map #(apply println %) ['(+ 1 1)])`:

1. `map` is evaluated => `#object[clojure.core$map]`
2. `#(apply println %)` is evaluated => `#object[fn]`
3. `['(+ 1 1)]` is evaluated => `[(+ 1 1)]` (printed representation of vector with list with one symbol and two numbers)
4. `#object[clojure.core$map]` is called with `#object[fn]` and `[(+ 1 1)]`

Now, you could look at `(source map)` to see, what exactly [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) does with its arguments (laziness, chunking...), but for the sake of simplicity, let's focus just on this small expression from the implementation:

```
(f (first s))
```

1. `f` is evaluated => `#object[fn]`
2. `first` is evaluated => `#object[clojure.core$first]`
3. `s` is evaluated => `[(+ 1 1)]`
4. `#object[clojure.core$first]` is called with `[(+ 1 1)]` => `(+ 1 1)`
5. `#object[fn]` (with body `(apply println %)`) is called with `(+ 1 1)`

   1. `apply` is evaluated => `#object[clojure.core$apply]`
   2. `println` is evaluated => `#object[clojure.core$println]`
   3. `%` is evaluated => `(+ 1 1)`
   4. `#object[clojure.core$apply]` is called with `#object[clojure.core$println]` and `(+ 1 1)`

You could now look at `(source apply)`- just the relevant part:

```
([^clojure.lang.IFn f args]
     (. f (applyTo (seq args))))
```

That is some Java interop, but as part of the evaluation, `args` evaluate to `(+ 1 1)`.

What is important: `(#(apply println %) '(+ 1 1))` is equivalent to `(apply println '(+ 1 1))` and that is equivalent to `(println '+ '1 '1)` and `(println '+ 1 1)`.

My point is- during evaluation, the expression `(+ 1 1)` is never evaluated (so you won't get `2` as the result), but some symbols and expressions are evaluated to `(+ 1 1)`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, and is nice to have with documentation links.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use `list` or `quote (')` makes no difference here.  Yes,
you are **always** providing "data" and data will never execute on its
own (you can `eval` the data to make it run).

This is a bit more tricky in a Lisp, as code is data, but to put it over
the top: this would be like expecting
`System.out.println("System.exit(1)")` to exit your program in Java.

So the way you're picturing the evaluation breaks at the `apply` step.

`apply` also only works with data.  It is a runtime operation: it
takes a list of arguments calls the given functions as if arguments
where given directly.

```clj
(apply println '(+ 1 2))
```

is actually equivalent to

```clj
(println '+ 1 2)
```

(this is where your train of thoughts is wrong (at the `--> apply the argument` step))

If you'd not `apply`, it would still just print the form

```clj
(println '(+ 1 2))
; → (+ 1 2)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Accepting a different answer that has links to documentation.  This was super helpful though -- I think the key to me understanding it was "apply only works with data -- it is a runtime operation."